# Is it possible to make custom select and copy toolbar in android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am making application based on viewpager with webview. but webview default select and copy toolbar sometimes work and sometimes not so i am trying to make custom select and copy toolbar so is it possible or not? advance in thanks.